# Enbedded fonts without src in static html

Tags: javascript, fonts

I generate an HTML-file which I want to send to other people. But i don't want to send a complete folder but only the pure html.
Therefore the generator should include everything in this HTML-file without linking to other sources. That means the HTML-file is "stand-alone".

Because of that i can't use images but want to use symbols of font.

Is there possibility to embedded all required information into that html for a font like "GLYPHICONS Halflings" without linking to any external (means outsite of the HTML) source?
I tried to use typeface-js already but i didn't worked.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

short answer no. you can send pure HTML with images, just put image links from the internet into the HTML tags to show image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The question qas not to send/embedded images but fonts. Or is this also not possible at all?